# How can I make a delay for sending an ajax request?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax

Here is my code:

```
$("input").on('keydown', function(){
    $.ajax({
        url :  '/files/tags_autocomplete.php',
        dataType : 'JSON',
        success : function (tags) {
            $("ul").html(tags.output);
        }
    });
});
```

My code suggests some tags *(the ones that have a matched substring  with what the user has written so far)* to user as an autocomplete box when he is typing his tags.

**What's my problem?** My current code sends a new ajax request per each *keydown*. For example, if the user writes `something`, my script sends 9 ajax requests which seems like a nightmare.

Anyway, how can I handle that? I mean do I need to implement a delay for sending? Something like *"don't send the request until 1 sec after last character inserted"*? or is there any better idea?

Comment: You might consider jQuery UI autocomplete. It has your requested functionality built in. http://jqueryui.com/autocomplete/. It might not be worth using *just* for autocomplete, but it's worth a look.

Comment: @JasonP Thank you for the link you provided .. but I seen that before .. and yes exactly as you said, using it just for autocomplete isn't affordable. though I heard we can download every part of jQuery UI we need *(for example, we can download only autocomplete part)*

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You could create a simple throttle mechanism

```
$("input").on('keydown', function(){

    clearTimeout( $(this).data('timer'); )

    var timer = setTimeout(function() {
      $.ajax({
          url :  '/files/tags_autocomplete.php',
          dataType : 'JSON',
          success : function (tags) {
              $("ul").html(tags.output);
          }
      });
    }, 500);

    $(this).data('timer', timer);
});
```

Comment: Oh, great .. I was something exactly like this .. upvote. Just for my information, is this a standard approach? For example how stackoverflow does it?

Comment: @MartinAJ - It's not uncommon. I have no idea what SO does ?

Comment: I meant was [how SO handle this](http://i.stack.imgur.com/8tuTU.png) ... but never mind.

Comment: Ok well, now there is a small problem .. when the user writes `java` and waits `0.5 sec`, a request will be sent for `java` input. then before returning matched tags by php script, the user continues to writing and makes it `javascript`. in this case, first the result of `java` input will be shown, and then after a while the result of `javascript` input. I want to know, can I **abort** everything when the user starts writing again? *(even when a request has been sent and no result returned yet)*

Comment: That's generally not an issue, as most servers will return results almost instantly, but if your server is slow or is returning large datasets, you can try to play with the timeout and shorten the 500ms a little etc. You could probably abort the ajax call as well, but it does get a little more complicated, and you can't always abort calls that have been made etc. but maybe some variaton of something like this would work -> https://jsfiddle.net/adeneo/kzgzponL/

Comment: Sorry to ping you again, just one thing: Defining `timeout` within each `keydown` event could cause issue? I mean you appear to define `xhr` inside of `setTimeout;` how can `xhr : xhr` at `$(this).data({timer : timer, xhr : xhr});` reference `xhr` within `setTimeout` which occurs 500 ms after `$(this).data({timer : timer, xhr : xhr});` call?

Comment: At the time that line runs, `xhr` wouldn't be the ajax request, that is correct. Only after 500ms would `xhr` be the ajax request, but that's the only time it would need to be aborted, so it should work just fine.

Comment: Maybe you want to take a look at [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39714740/cannot-use-in-operator-to-search-for-sth-in-undefined).

Comment: @MartinAJ - aah, I see the issue there, the answers you've gotten is the same as this one before I added the aborts you wanted, so I'll roll this answer back, and the aborts in the other questions, hopefully working this time, as I just forgot to check the object before using `in`, and that's really the only change needed.

Comment: Seems nice, Upvote. But honestly I cannot understand how your code works. Can you please add some explanations to your answer and explain why you remove `timeOut` in the first of your code and set it in the end of your code?! What's the reason?!

Comment: @stack - every time the user types something, a timeout is set so that the ajax calls happens a little later. If the user types something more, the previous timeout is cleared, and a new timeout is set. That way, the ajax call only happens when the user stops typing for more than half a second (500ms), effectively throttling the calls.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation. But my main confusion is what's the reason of using `.data()` in this case? What's wrong whit [this](https://jsfiddle.net/vj5ojtck/)?

Comment: @stack - That example has the variable inside the function, so it won't "remember" it the next time the function is called. It has to be like [this](https://jsfiddle.net/adeneo/vj5ojtck/1/), but I'm just using `data()` to avoid the global variable and to store the timer on each element in case there are multiple elements matching the selector.

Comment: @adeneo - How can I use the timer function to delay the success callback of an **Ajax** call (which is being used in tandem with Django view)? The scenario will be, variables are sent as an array to the **Django function** and after processing all the inputs, the callback should happen **after a certain delay**. Without a delay in place the setup is otherwise working but **sometimes the view throws up the intermediate values (results) too**.