# Cannot use 'in' operator to search for 'sth' in undefined

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

Here is my code:

```
.
.
keydown: function(ev) {

    clearTimeout( $(this).data('timer') );
    if ( 'abort' in $(this).data('xhr') ) $(this).data('xhr').abort();       // error here
    var xhr, timer = setTimeout(function() {
        xhr = $.ajax({
            url :  '/files/tags_autocomplete.php',
            dataType : 'JSON',
            success : function (tags) {
            $("ul").html(tags.output);
            }
        });
    }, 500);

    $(this).data({timer : timer, xhr : xhr});
}
.
.
```

As I've commented, third line throws this error:

> **Uncaught TypeError:** Cannot use 'in' operator to search for 'abort' in undefined

How can I fix it?

Comment: [in](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/in) is used to find a property in an object or array, I don't think `$(this).data("xhr")` is either

Comment: @SterlingArcher `$(this).data("xhr")` is the value of the `xhr` variable, which is a `jqXHR` object returned by `$.ajax`.

Comment: Shoot, I thought it was a data attribute. My mistake.

Answer (score 4):

The issue here is that the [`undefined`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/undefined) value does not have any properties. You need to perform a check on the return value of `data()` to check that it isn't undefined.

```
var xhr = $(this).data('xhr');
if(typeof xhr !== 'undefiend' && xhr.abort) {
    // do your code here
}
```

Replace your `if` statement with the above 4 lines of code.

Answer (score 2):

Change from:

```
if ('abort' in $(this).data('xhr') ) $(this).data('xhr').abort();
```

to:

```
if ($(this).data('xhr') && $(this).data('xhr').abort) {
  $(this).data('xhr').abort(); 
}
```

Problem was simply checking if object has `xhr` element. By default it does not exist so it's `undefined`, and you were asking JS engine to find an element in `undefined` information that was causing error.

So that's why I added to check if it has `.data('xhr')` because for JS `undefined` is treated as `false` and after that I checked if `data('xhr')` has `abort` attribute.

By the way if you want to stop timer when key is pressed it's better to just clear timeout and it will not run AJAX call, so no need to put XHR object to element's data storage:

```
if($(this).data('timer')) {
  clearTimeout($(this).data('timer'));
}

var timer = setTimeout(function() {
    $.ajax({
        url :  '/files/tags_autocomplete.php',
        dataType : 'JSON',
        success : function (tags) {
          $("ul").html(tags.output);
        }
    });
}, 500);

$(this).data('timer', timer);
```

or even simpler (without data storage):

```
if(window.autocompleteTimer) {
  clearTimeout(window.autocompleteTimer);
}

window.autocompleteTimer = setTimeout(function() {
    $.ajax({
        url :  '/files/tags_autocomplete.php',
        dataType : 'JSON',
        success : function (tags) {
          $("ul").html(tags.output);
        }
    });
}, 500);
```

Comment: `$(this).data('xhr')` seems like a great candidate for a variable.

Comment: @4castle haha (: I've just gave solution of question. But it's not right to keep objects and/or functions in data-* attributes

Answer (score 2):

The issue is that if the user types again before 500ms has passed, `$(this).data('xhr')` would be undefined, as it's not yet set to the ajax request.

As we can't use the `in` operator on `undefined`, only on objects, the correct solution to both clear the timeout and abort any pending requests, would be to just check if `$(this).data('xhr')` has been set, and is an object, before checking if it has an `abort` property

```
keydown: function(ev) {
  var self = $(this);

  clearTimeout(self.data('timer'));

  if (typeof self.data('xhr') === 'object' && 'abort' in self.data('xhr')) {
    self.data('xhr').abort();
  }

  var timer = setTimeout(function() {
    self.data('xhr', $.ajax({
      url: '/files/tags_autocomplete.php',
      dataType: 'JSON',
      success: function(tags) {
        $("ul").html(tags.output);
      }
    }));
  }, 500);

  self.data('timer', timer);
```